# unable to install/import tkinter

Tags: 14.04, python3, pip

I got a pretty confusing Problem:

I build a python program using tkinter. Then I dist-upgraded my ubuntu 13.10 (amd64) to ubuntu 14.04 LTS, now I tried to run my tkinter program. My compiler told me

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

(The same with Tkinter or tk/Tk)
Then I tried to reinstall tkinter using pip:

```
$ pip install tkinter


Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tkinter
   Cleaning up...
   No distributions at all found for tkinter
```

again the same with Tkinter, tkinter, tk and Tk

So what happened?
Have I got to run something like

```
$ pip update
```

(because tk is not anymore in the pip-repository)
But why is  it not installed anymore on my pc?

Edit:
1. I do not have no root access
2. in the pip.log is

```
>

  Downloading/unpacking tk   Getting page
> https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/   Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/: 404 Client Error: Not Found   Will
> skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/ when looking for download
> links for tk   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/   URLs to
> search for versions for tk:   * https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/  
> Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/   Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/: 404 Client Error: Not Found   Will
> skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tk/ when looking for download
> links for tk   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the
> requirement tk
```

something pretty close happened when I tried To install something using apt on my RaspberryPi without running

```
$ apt-get update
```

for a few months

I'd be glad for some help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`python-tk` cannot be installed using pip.

As tk is TkInter (-> Interface to TK, which is written in C(++) ) you need to install the C(++) Library TK.

you cannot install this library using `pip`, as `pip` is designed to install (mainly)[1]pure python packages. By the way you would not have the sufficient rights to install the library. So you need to ask your superuser for help.

The only way to install it is using

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk # python2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk #python3
```

And last but not least you would have to use `pip3` to install packages for `python3`.

It is the same as you cannot install `freetype` using `pip`.

***Note***: it is better to use `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3`, as there might be multiple `python3` installations on your machine (e.g. `python3.4` and `python3.5.1`)

[1]: Actually pip is able to compile C/C++ Libraries, but it does not seem like it is able to install System-Libraries. Or one will create this package in future.

Comment: So Tkinter can not be installed via pip. Does this mean, the program which uses Tkinter, can not use virtualenv ?

Comment: `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` ( you should use `virtualenvwrapper`) are able to use system packages, so you can use `tk`, but no custom `tk` installtion in your vitualenv.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way with Python's Wheel package manager  to install the binary packages like this one?

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

or, since your question is tagged as python3, this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: I tried( on a RaspberryPi) did not work.

Comment: Didn't work as in...

Comment: I tried running it on my Raspberry Pi and It didn't work

Comment: I got that much of. How did it not work? Any errors? What?

Comment: the same thing: 'there is no package called python-tk' that was the error.Of course I tried also 'python-Tk' and so on

Comment: You sure you're running Ubuntu 14.04? Have you updated your sources? It's available on my machine

Comment: How can I update my sources?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16111/discussion-between-littlebyblue-and-elefantphace).

Comment: By using `apt-get update`

Comment: I can't run it because im not root. By the way you're correcting my spelling mistakes?

Comment: Just making edits where I see needed.

Comment: My System Administrator fixed it for me

Comment: "python-tk is already the newest version."

Comment: @DaleE.Moore check out my answer this answer here is wrong