# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: 20.04, python3, pycharm

The aforementioned error showed up when I tried to use the `Turtle` class. I was following a tutorial where it's used to pop up a window in the screen. The code is simple:

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
jabba = Turtle()
print(jabba)

my_screen = Screen()
print(my_screen.canvheight)
my_screen.exitonclick()
```

But in the terminal it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 using PyCharm professional IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to install/import tkinter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505141/unable-to-install-import-tkinter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing `python3-tk` solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this command on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```